Multiple number values from input to PostgreSQL database (QGIS Model Designer)
I'm creating a model in QGIS to calculate isochrones with PostGIS (pgrouting). Currently a user can input a single time value (on the screenshot, it's in Time threshold in minutes input), then this  value is added to the network dataset which is later exported in Postgres database.
In CREATE TABLE route walking there's a query that is calculating driving distance with this code:
CREATE TABLE route_walking AS
SELECT * FROM pgr_drivingDistance(
    'SELECT network.id_0 as id, source, target, traveltime_walking as cost FROM network', --calculate driving distance
    ARRAY(SELECT node_id FROM origins), --origin points for calculating driving distance 
    (SELECT network.time from network limit 1), --time value from the input
    false
)

After that the isochrones are calculated.
I want to have an option to enter multiple time values (not only single value) and calculate isochrones using these values. I don't really know how to do it since there's no loop input options or something like that in Model Designer. How to do it?

